# Is there any possibility to create services to achievement module in Drupal?

Tags: services

I have using the [Achievements](https://www.drupal.org/project/achievements) module in my site, it's working fine.

- I have one doubt, I'm using the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module to consuming user nodes and user details.

But is there any possibility to perform services CRUD operations to **achievements** module by using services module?

Comment: You cold create your own custom resource and use the module api to achieve your goal here is a good [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/783460) to build new resource. After that you need to check the module source code and use its api to build callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an existing integration between Achievements and Services (not one that Google is up for divulging, at least), so you would need to code that yourself. But yes, it's very possible, as both modules are well written.

For full details, check out the [Services API docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/113699) and the [Achievements API docs](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/achievements/tree/achievements.api.php?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-1.x).